# How to get all subtitle streams recorded in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i "xxxxxxx" -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy -y -f mpegts test.ts
```

Gives only one subtitle stream, how do I record them all?

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'xx':
  Duration: N/A, start: 24264.769756, bitrate: N/A
  Program 111
    Stream #0:0[0x83e]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x83f]: Audio: ac3 ([129][0][0][0] / 0x0081), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x841]: Audio: mp3 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 0 channels
    Stream #0:3[0x840]: Audio: mp3 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 0 channels
    Stream #0:4[0x842]: Audio: mp3 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 0 channels
    Stream #0:5[0x853](tai): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:6[0x854](may): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:7[0x855](vie): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:8[0x856](tha): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:9[0x857](ind): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:10[0x858](bur): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
```

Comment: Do you want all audio streams as well?

Comment: Only the first audio track.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how `-c` (select codecs) & `-map` (select streams) options work:

```
-c:a -> select best supported audio (transcoded)
-c:a copy -> best supported audio (copied)
-map 0:a -> all audio from 1st input file (transcoded)
-map 1:a:0 -> 1st audio stream from 2nd input file (transcoded)
-map 1:a:1 -c:a copy -> 2nd audio stream from 2nd input file (copied)
```

Check out [this link](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-handling) for stream selection & handling.

To copy all subtitle streams from 1st input file without transcoding:

```
-map 0:s -c:s copy
```

Your code was OK, just the `map` option was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Without any `-map` options, ffmpeg will only pick one stream of any supported type: video, audio, subtitles.

So, add map options to pick the required stream.

```
ffmpeg -i "xxxxxxx" -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:s -c copy -y -f mpegts test.ts
```

Comment: And for those who just want all streams (video, audio and subtitles): `-map 0 -c copy` ( https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map#Example9 )